# How to run GitHub Code quickly when your environment missing modules?

Tags: python, web, flask

- I would like to run the following project:
  https://github.com/pyl0ne/flaskSaaS
- At the 2nd step of executing causes the error
- `python manage.py initdb` (if I run it like this it has no problem, but he have run it with python3 with no problem as well: https://youtu.be/NzmoPqte4V4?t=1623 )
- I Do want to run it with python 3 so instead I use:
  `python3 manage.py initdb`
- To run it in python3 I have corrected in the code manage file:
- ORIGINAL (tried with this one before): `from flask.ext.script import Manager, prompt_bool, Shell, Server`
- Mine: `from flask_script import Manager, prompt_bool, Shell, Server`
  based on: [importerror: no module named flask.ext.script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33675594/importerror-no-module-named-flask-ext-script)
- I have tried to run it in PyCharm directly and checked the DE's interpreter all set to python 3.7 [importerror: no module named flask.ext.script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33675594/importerror-no-module-named-flask-ext-script) (It gives errors similar to the terminal)

#### Final Error:

```
Beli:flaskSaaS-master peterSimon$ python3 manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask_script import Manager, prompt_bool, Shell, Server #ORIGINAL: from flask.ext.script import Manager, prompt_bool, Shell, Server
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_script'
```

Comment: Have you installed the flask_script module?

Comment: what is the output of `make install && make dev`? No failure here?

Comment: Now I am (I thought that is installed with flask already). `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'termcolor' ` I have run the `pip install -r requirements.txt` `pip3 install -r requirements.txt` before the project so it should be all right

Comment: `make install && make dev` perfectly runs here, if I keep the original code it sets up the server as well but I want to expand the project in python3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get rid of confusion by using [a virtual environment](https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/). So you only have one Python interpreter (version 3.x) and one pip version for this Python version:

```
git clone git@github.com:pyl0ne/flaskSaaS.git
cd flaskSaaS/
python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
make install
python manage.py initdb
```

should work.

Comment: After I execute the final command `python manage.py runserver` ERROR message: `OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: '/Users/.../flaskSaaS-master/manage.py' `

Comment: Do you have virtual environment activated via `source venv/bin/activate` in each shell you're using for this project? Otherwise [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55315103/oserror-errno-8-exec-format-error-when-trying-to-run-simple-flask-app-in-a) could be helpful. Maybe a VM could be a better choice instead of using only a virtual environment. It seems that your OS, your environment variables or whatever are messed up. So a VM could be a good workaround, at least a test if everything would work as expected outside your system.

Comment: I am using MacOS Sierra 10.12.6 . I have used the exaact code you have provided in your post. I have used this(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55315103/oserror-errno-8-exec-format-error-when-trying-to-run-simple-flask-app-in-a) but it dit not help because I am seting up a local VM not docker on the MacOS Terminal.

Comment: I didn't understand?! Are you using MacOS or a VM with Linux or what? Btw: [This](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/issues/1482#issuecomment-477437009) is maybe a better link.

Comment: I am using your code above that sets up a venv on macos .

Comment: I ahve noticed this: `#!/usr/local/bin/python3` (https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/issues/1482#issuecomment-477437009) and `#!/usr/bin/env python3.6` ( https://gist.github.com/teruroom/389cde239aed7d62b0f43ce074a646df ) OR `#!/bin/sh` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26807937/subprocess-popen-oserror-errno-8-exec-format-error-in-python) But I dont know where to put it in ( https://github.com/pyl0ne/flaskSaaS )

Answer (score 0):

Check if `make install` actually installed `flask_script`.

If not, do `pip install Flask-Script`

and for python3

`pip3 install Flask-Script`

Comment: pip3 install Flask-Script helped but it brought up the following error: ```Beli:flaskSaaS-master peterSimon$ python3 manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 2, in <module>
    from termcolor import colored
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'termcolor' ```

Comment: At the beginign of the project I have run: `pip install -r requirements.txt` `pip3 install -r requirements.txt` so it should be all right

Comment: from the second error you got it looks like your environment isn't sat up properly